# OEM versus aftermarket pads/rotors for Volvo?

Tags: brakes, volvo, 850

I had some new rims put on my 1996 Volvo 850 today and the dealer said I need to have a brake job done. He specifically said I should be sure to get OEM pads and rotors because Volvos in particular are sensitive to having OEM brake components.

I read some of the posts on Matthew's Volvo Site about this and there seemed to be some disagreement about whether OEM brake parts were to be preferred over aftermarket.

Going with OEM certainly seems to be the safe bet. Getting cheap aftermarket brake parts would seem to be a bad idea. So, I guess the only remaining question is whether expensive aftermarket brake components would be superior to OEM pads/rotors?

Answer (score 3):

Volvo has used Brembo and ATE as suppliers for their oem brakes so you won’t go far wrong with those.

Do have a look at the make of what is fitted as the pads have to match the caliper...

Comment: It could be worth joining a volvo forum as they are all very dedicated and helpful...